# ODBC Access2010 MySQL connection error

Tags: mysql, odbc, ms-access-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql server does not support 4-byte encoded utf8 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890693/mysql-server-does-not-support-4-byte-encoded-utf8-characters)

I have a 64 bit OS, and Microsoft Access 2010 and remote MySQL 4.1.13 (I have the credentials). I downloaded the 32 bit ODBC connector and installed it. After linking the tables when I try to insert data, I'm getting the following error:

```
Run-time error '3155':

ODBC- insert on a linked table 'sometable' failed.

[MySQL] [ODBC 5.2 (w) Driver] [mysqld-4.1.13-standard] Server does not support
4-byte encoded UTF8 characters. (#0)
```

I have no idea what this means? I really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 32bit Access and a 32 bit ODBC driver installed, make sure to create a 32 bit data source. the standard dialog via windows system configuration only lets you create 64 bit drivers on a 64 bit windows

Comment: Mine is 32 bit access, and like you said I created the dsn by clicking the odbcad32.exe in the SysWOW64 folder. But no luck, I'm getting the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, unless you can somehow get rid of the characters causing this error an replace them with valid ones, you would have to update mysql server.